# Validate HTML form using JSON rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, validation

I want to create a form using JSON and also need to validate the rules defined in JSON.

Below is how my JSON looks:

```
{
   "modules":[
      {
         "type":"form",
         "action":"submit.aspx",
         "name":"registrationform",
         "container":"#maincontent",
         "fields":[
            {
               "id":"firstname",
               "label":"First Name",
               "name":"fname",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "id":"email",
               "label":"Email",
               "name":"email",
               "type":"text",
               "value":""
            }
         ],
         "rules":
            {
                "fname" : "required", 
                "email"     :   {
                                    "required": "true",
                                    "email": "true"
                                }
            },
         "messages":
            {
                "fname" : "Enter your firstname",
                "email" :   {
                                "required": "Please enter a valid email address",
                                "minlength": "Please enter a valid email address"
                            }
            }
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I write dynamic code that would validate my form elements using the JSON rules and display error messages (as defined in JSON) ?

Is there some jQuery method that I can use directly?

Comment: Look up jquery validate (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).  You can then translate your rules and messages into jquery validate validation rules.  It shouldn't be too hard!

Comment: Can I do it without any plugin? like using jquery method ...

Comment: You can but you'd basically be duplicating jquery validate functionality.  You'd capture the form submit event, loop through your rules, run custom validation based on the rule (if required, make sure has value (and value isn't just whitespace), etc).  But all that logic is already in the validate plugin, so I'd strongly recommend using it.